# Is it possible to detect SSL-Sites that have included "insecure content" in PhantomJS

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, phantomjs

I want to automatically check if a HTTPS page includes "insecure content" eg HTTP content.

Is there a way to automatically determine that?

It seems phantom just loads the content and ignores that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like a charm:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');

var page = new WebPage();
page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
  if(/^https/.exec(request.url)) {
    console.log('i am fine with ' + request.url)
  } else {
    console.log('i dont like ' + request.url)
  }
}

page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
var url = "https://example.com";

page.open(url, function (status) {
  if(status == 'success') {
    page.render('test.png');
    console.log('loaded')
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. Thank you.
I would just suggest checking it really catches all resources and there are no opened phantomjs bugs related to the event.